# How do I cross-compile a Linux kernel to a MIPS little endian host?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mips, cross-compiling

The kernel in question is **2.6.18**. If I call

```
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mipsel-linux- menuconfig
```

there will be only the option to build a big endian kernel in the menu. If I use **ARCH=mipsel**, it will complain about not having an **arch/mipsel** dir.

How's this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the first menu entry `Machine selection`. You must first select a machine, which supports little endian architecture. For example `Broadcom BCM4747XX` or `Alchemy processor`.

Then you go to the next menu entry `Endianness selection`, where you can either choose between `Little endian` and `Big endian` or where it is preselected, if only one of them is supported.